# Finding bug in segment tree implementation

Tags: segment-tree

I was trying to solve this problem - [link](http://lightoj.com/volume_showproblem.php?problem=1164). Segment Tree with Lazy Propagation. But I dont know where I made mistake. Please help me find the bug.
I am new to Segment Tree with Lazy Propagation. But my code seems ok.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
const int MAXN = 100000; 
struct info{ long long sum, prop; }; info tree[300010];
void update(int node, int l, int r, int i, int j,  int val) {
    if( i > r || j < l) return; 
    if(i <= l && j >= r) {
        tree[node].sum += (r-l+1)*val; 
        tree[node].prop += val;
        return;
    } int left = node*2, right = left|1, mid = (l+r)/2;
    update(left, l, mid, i,j,val); 
    update(right, mid+1, r, i,j,val);
    tree[node].sum = tree[left].sum + tree[right].sum + (r-l+1)*tree[node].prop;
}
long long query(int node, int l, int r, int i, int j, long long carry = 0) {
    if(i > r || j < l ) return 0;
    if(i <= l && j >= r) return tree[node].sum + (r-l+1)*carry;
    int mid = (l+r)/2, left = node*2, right = left|1; 
    long long ret = query(left, l, mid, i,j, carry + tree[node].prop); 
    ret += query(right,mid+1,r,i,j, carry + tree[node].prop);
    return ret;
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("in", "r", stdin);
#endif
    int t,co=0; scanf("%d", &t); while(t--) {
        int n, q; scanf("%d %d", &n, &q);
        for(int i=0; i<=3*n; i++) tree[i].sum = tree[i].prop = 0;
        printf("Case %d:\n", ++co);
        while(q--) { 
            int type,a,b,c; scanf("%d", &type); if(!type) {
                scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c); 
                update(1, 0, n-1, a,b,c);
            } else {
                scanf("%d %d", &a, &b); 
                printf("%d\n", query(1, 0, n-1, a,b));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A login and password is required to visit the link in your question. It might work better to put the problem rather than a link in the problem. How do you know there is a bug in your code? What steps could someone on stackoverflow take to reproduce the bug in your code?

Comment: @SethDifley The problem is basic application of lazy propagation .... 
0 x y v - this query adds v to range [x,y]. and 1 x y will output the sum of numbers in range [x,y]. all 0-indexed....

Comment: @A_J Actually I am trying to implement lazy propagation .. this is my work... But Submitting this into the OJ gave me wrong answer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this site is not for finding bug in code. Try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for this purpose.

Anyway In your code return type of function `query()` is long long but in `main` you are printing integer type. change `printf("%d\n", query(1, 0, n-1, a,b));` to `printf("%lld\n", query(1, 0, n-1, a,b));` and I hope you will get AC.